# gdata get contacts from a certain group

Tags: gdata-api, google-contacts-api

How can I retrieve all my contacts that belong to a certain group? I don't want a complete list of all my contacts just the ones from a specific group.

This is the group:
DEBUG    2009-07-28 12:01:32,681 helloworld.py:21] group is Customers with id http://www.google.com/
m8/feeds/groups/XXXX%40gmail.com/base/XXXX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer, should any one run into the same problem, here is a solution. I only have on contact group, so it's no big problem to manage.

once you are logged in you can get all your groups using the following method:

```
groups = gd_client.GetGroupsFeed()
```

and since I only have one, I can just pop it off like this:

```
group = groups.entry.pop()
```

now all I have to do is this:

```
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
query.max_results = 1000
query.group = group.id.text

gd_feed = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
```

enjoy

Comment: can u share me the original lines?